# MS Excel Structured Reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

[image]i have this Excel Assigment that asked this question

```
Create a structured reference in cell H4 that will multiply the Streaming_Revenues 
amount by the value in cell B2 if the Rating is PG-13. Otherwise, it will display 0
```

how can i get this done? i tried

```
=if(B2="PG-13", G2*B2, 0)
```

Comment: I think that your formula is correct but I also think that the cell for the "rating" is not supposed to be B2?

Comment: i tried this `=IF(Table1[Rating]="PG-13",Table1[Streaming_Revenues]*$B$2,"0")` still not

Comment: what do u think will work?

Comment: What do you mean by "still not"? Does the formula give inexpected results? If you create the formula by pointing and clicking at the right cells, you should have gotten the right structured references automatically. Perhaps there is a problem with the data?

Comment: yeah. am using MyItLab

Comment: GREAT! you attached a photo :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula

```
=IF(Table1[rating]="PG-13",Table1[Streaming_Revenues]*$B$2,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if anyone comes across this question the correct answer is:

```
=IF([Rating]="PG-13",[Streaming_Revenues]*$B$2,0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I agree with Kim Jaca, I think you want it to reference B4 like this:

```
=if(B4="PG-13",G4*$B$2,0)
```

use the F4 key to lock in your B2 cell. Good luck.

Comment: This one should work. if still not then I agree with @jkpieterse that there might be a problem with the data or on the format of cells.

Answer (score -1):

```
=IF([Rating]="PG-13", [Streaming_Revenues]*$B$2,0)
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.